# How to do Fade in and Fade out in Image view by using Transitions on Android programmatically?

Tags: android, image, fadein, transition, fadeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use fade in and fade out effect with an image using Transition, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275993/how-to-use-fade-in-and-fade-out-effect-with-an-image-using-transition-android)

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

I have seen this link. It shows images by using Fade in and Fade out effects. How could I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create two `Animation`

   ```
   Animation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);  
   Animation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
   ```
2. set duration

   ```
   fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(1000);
   fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1000);
   ```
3. set listener - when the fadeout animation finish replace the image

   ```
   fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

           @Override
           public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
           }

           @Override
           public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                               }

           @Override
           public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
               //here switch the images !
               //and the begin the second animation FadeIn 
           }
       });
   ```
4. ImageView.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);

Comment: whats the difference between setAnimation and startAnimation ?