# Animating ImageView Transition

Tags: android

Basically, my code has a couple of pictures involved  but the transition is blunt. Tried using .animation and .animationSet but it didn't change anything and I'm not sure why.

```
ImageView img;
int[] drawables = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5}; 
int counter = 0;

public void changeImage(){  //switches images
    if (counter == 5){
        counter = 0;
    }
    img.setImageResource(drawables[counter]);
    counter++;
}

public void animate(){  //supposed to animate transitions
    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);

    fadeIn.setDuration(3000);
    fadeOut.setDuration(3000);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());  // i dont know what they do but another  
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // user said it was useful. Could you explain?

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
    img.setAnimation(set);
}

changeImage();
animate();
```

I figured it'll be cooler if there was a method that called for both start and end images as input.
Also where can i find the index for other kinds of animation other than fade-in and fade-out.

N.B.: the changeImage() and animate() methods are called by a button.OnClickedAction()

Comment: Is the image supposed to change after a specific time? or a touch will change it?

Comment: have you tried looking at [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)s?

Comment: Is the image supposed to change after a specific time? or a touch will change it? An interpolator is used to define the rate of change of animation. Have a look at http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/view/animation/DecelerateInterpolator.java.html

Comment: @saopayne yes, when a button is clicked.

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275993/how-to-use-fade-in-and-fade-out-effect-with-an-image-using-transition-android  , do let us have your feedback.

Comment: @panini how do i use TransitionDrawables if my images are defined in the res folder

Comment: animation.start() wouldn't hurt

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419141/fading-in-text-in-android-using-animationutils-loadanimation.